# Mouseenter not working in chrome with YUI

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, yui, mouseenter

```
 YAHOO.util.Event.on("divName", "mouseenter", function (e) {    }
```

This code is working in all browsers except chrome. Is there any issue with YUI 2.x  for chrome.

Comment: Is this throwing any errors? In the code example, you're missing a closing parens, could that be it? What version of chrome are you running. What is the associated HTML for this?

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, it worked in all browsers when I used the following code.

```
document.getElementById("divName").onmouseover = function() {
      // code to run when the user hovers over the div

    };
```

Comment: There is difference between mouseover and mouseenter, In some cases you have to use mouseenter, mouseover will not do the trick